# Replace a set of html br elements with another in jQuery -- parsing HTML with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-parsing

So here's my problem. I have a little third-party service on my site that generates a bunch of HTML from an RSS feed and sticks it in my webpage when the page is loaded. However, when it generates the HTML, it inserts a bunch of totally unnecessary break tags. Unfortunately, the source file that generates this code is on the third party's server and not mine, so I can't tweak it.

Thus, I'm trying to tweak the HTML right before the page is loaded by using a little jQuery inside the onLoad="" property in the body tag. However, I can't simply use something like $('br').remove(); because then there aren't ANY break tags, and I need one per each spot where there are currently three.

So ultimately, what I need to do is come up with a jQuery statement that replaces

```
<br><br clear=all><br>
```

with

```
<br />
```

I'm rather new to jQuery, but I couldn't seem to find anything that would help me do this. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [Next Adjacent Selector (+)](http://api.jquery.com/next-adjacent-Selector/):

```
$("br+br").remove(); //Removes all <br> tags in front of another
```

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6LZBv/)

Comment: This was by far the easiest solution (that worked). Thanks a lot for suggestion and the demo!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming they are in the exact format you gave, you can do this:

```
var br = $('br[clear="all"]');
br.attr('clear', '');
br.prev('br').remove();
br.next('br').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can play with selector attributes, not inside the onload but inside the jquery ready (http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

> $('br[clear=all]').remove();

more details on selector attribute:http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

Answer (score 0):

Why donn`t just replace the html of the RSS HTML container:

```
  yourContainerElem.innerHTML =  yourContainerElem.innerHTML.replace(/<br><br clear=all><br>/gi, '<br />');
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove all but one:

```
$('br,[clear!="all"]').remove()
```

Then to remove the 'clear=all':

```
$('br').removeAttribute('clear')
```

Answer (score -1):

You better do this with regexps not with jquery. Simplest example:

```
string.replace('<br><br clear=all><br>', '<br />')
```

Comment: horrible to parse HTML with regex, use a parser for this